# cts:triple-range-query with triple in document propties

Tags: marklogic

I would like to to execute a cts:triple-range-query as illustrated in the example section on https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:triple-range-query. However, I put the triple in the document properties.

[image]

Unfortunately, the following query does not return the document.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $query := cts:triple-range-query(
  sem:iri("http://example.com/Mark"),
  sem:iri("http://example.com/ns/person#age"),
  50,
  "<"
)
return cts:search(fn:doc(), $query)
```

How can I make the query work with triples stored in the document properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try encapsulating your query in [cts:properties-fragment-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:properties-fragment-query) like so:

```
return cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:properties-fragment-query($query))
```

You will probably achieve more performant results as you scale out by instead using the [envelope](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/envelope-design-pattern/) or sidecar (2nd document with deterministic URI) design patterns.

Comment: Thanks! cts:properties-fragment-query solves the problem. I will also consider the other design patterns in case we are facing performance problems.